# Defining the correct Apache document root

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webserver, opensuse

I am pretty new to Linux and I tried to install & configure the Apache 2 on OpenSuse 12.1.

Is this the document-root? `/home/username/public_html`

is this correct!? see the page 3 /or 4 of the configuration guide of the HTTP server.

```
Document Root: "/srv/www/htdocs"
Directory; "/srv/www/htdocs"
Alias: /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"
Directory: "/usr/share/apache2/icons"
Script Alias: /cgi-bin/ "/srv/www/cgi-bin/"
Directory: "/srv/www/cgi-bin"
mod_userdir.c: empty here nothing is filled in ;-)
include: /etc/apache2/conf.d/*.conf
include: /etc/apache2/conf.d/apache2-manual?conf
Servername linux-r4qe
E-Mail des Servername: root@linux-r4qe
```

While running the apache-configuring tool I have on page 5/5

```
listening on
all, port 80
Standardhost
in 
SSL deaktiviert
Virtuelle Hosts
linux-r4qe in "/srv/www/htdocs", SSL deaktiviert
```

Is Apache installed and configured correctly?

As you might find this question a bit silly or newbie-like, here are some explanations: I have installed the LAMP some months ago - but in a wrong path.

```
public $unicodeslugs = '0';
    public $feed_limit = '10';
    public $log_path = '/srv/www/htdocs/basic/logs';
    public $tmp_path = '/srv/www/htdocs/basic/tmp';
    public $lifetime = '15';
    public $session_handler = 'database';
}
```

I always thougth that the path should be this one here:

```
/home/username/public_html
```

**Update** - especially for Oliver Salzburg

see here the both links

[link one with some descriptions on the OpenSuse-Case](http://forums.opensuse.org/forums/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/473162-installation-configuation-apache-2-opensuse-12-1-quick-walktrough.html#post2446354)
[detailed description on openSuse and some Advices that are discussed over there](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/470661-lampp-file-permissions-causes-terrific-errors-server.html)

Comment: `~` is already a placeholder for `/home/username/`. So `~/username/` would be incorrect. Also, what configuration guide are you talking about?

Comment: i installed in opensuse - and i took YAST

Answer (score 0):

`/home/username/public_html` is used in **addition** to the default web root when [`mod_userdir`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html) is loaded.

Some people use that functionality to put a website inside a users home directory. But it's by no means the *standard* way of doing things.

The document root for a given Apache site configuration is defined by the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive.

Yours is set to `/srv/www/htdocs`, which, to my understanding, is the default location in OpenSUSE.

Comment: thx alot. 
In openSUSE, when we install a LAMP solution, usually we run the server in this folder : ~/username/public_html.

So - one question did i install the Apache in srv/www, those folders belong to root. So we should change the ownership of those folders like that in terminal :

Code:

su -
password
your_hostname:/home/the_user_to_give_ownership # chown -R the_user_to_give_ownership:users /srv/www

Comment: Is that quoted from somewhere? It sounds like horrible advise, but that could be just because it's SUSE.

Comment: hello Dear Oliver well - i have added two links in the inital posting! scroll to the end of the initial posting) Especially in the **second link** you can see what the OpenSuse-folks adviced me. ... would love to hear again from you - many greetings from Heidelberg - approx  80 km in the south of FFM ;-)